# How to set the ALL USER Directory as an output directory for a installer created with NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I am trying to install a file to ALL USER DOCUMENTS Directory(windows 7) using NSIS.

In my code i am setting "SetShellVarContext all" but still the files are getting installed at current user directory

Please help

Here is my code

```
    # define installer name
    OutFile "installer.exe"

    # set desktop as install directory
    InstallDir $DOCUMENTS

    # default section start
    Section

    # define output path
    SetShellVarContext all
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR

    # specify file to go in output path
    File test.txt

    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe


    #-------
    # default section end
    SectionEnd

    # create a section to define what the uninstaller does.
    # the section will always be named "Uninstall"
    Section "Uninstall"

    # Always delete uninstaller first
    Delete $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe

    # now delete installed file
    Delete $INSTDIR\test.txt

    SectionEnd
```

Comment: Did you run your installer with elevated permission? i.e. 'Run as admin'

Comment: @hypheni: Probably, the example is missing RequestExectionLevel so it is probably elevated by the setup detection compatibility shim. If this detection is turned off you should get errors when trying to write the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetShellVarContext` does not affect the `InstallDir` attribute, you must manually set $InstDir:

```
Function .onInit
SetShellVarContext all
StrCpy $InstDir $Documents
FunctionEnd
```